# Can a Speedlite 430EX II be used on a Canon EOS 6D?

Tags: canon, flash, hotshoe-flash, compatibility

I recently purchased a [Canon EOS 6D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_6D), but my [Speedlite 430EX II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_flash_system#430_EX_and_430_EX_II) is not working with it. Is this flash not compatible with the 6D? When I go to Menu --> External Speedlite Control, flash firing is enabled.

However, when I press 'Flash function settings' or 'Flash C.Fn settings,' it says "This menu cannot be displayed. Incompatible flash or flash's power is turned off." (power is definitely not turned off :))

What is the issue?

Comment: I have used them together without problems. They should be entirely compatible. Have you used the flash on another camera body and/or used another flash on the camera body to rule out faulty gear?

Comment: Are you sure the flash is seated properly?

Comment: yeah, I've used the flash with 550d and it works fine. seems to be seated properly too.

Comment: oh god, there was something on the shoe blocking the censors. cleaned it and it seems to be work! i feel stupid for having this panic attack but thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Canon 430EX II is fully compatible with the Canon EOS 6D and should be able to do all of the functions for which it is designed. If you are having problems using your 430EX II with your EOS 6D, here are a few things you should check:

- **Batteries** Be sure the batteries for both the flash and the camera are properly charged.
- **Connection** Be sure the flash is seated properly on the camera's hot shoe. When both are new, the fit might be a little tight and it is easy to think the flash is slid all the way into the hot shoe when it is only partially inserted. Also check for any debris or other foreign material that may have inadvertently gotten between the connectors on the flash and camera.
- **Camera Settings** Check to make sure the flash is enabled to fire under 'Shooting Menu (Red) tab 2 → External Speedlight control → Flash firing → enable.